# Crear enum en Java desde archivo .properties

Tags: java, enum, archivo-de-propiedades

¿Es posible cargar desde archivo `.properties` valores para un enum?

Tengo en archivo llamado `secure.properties` la siguiente información:

```
authorization-api-context=http://localhost:8099/
mongo-db-name=secure
defaul-countries="COL;ARG;PER"
```

y quisiera crear un enum con los países por defecto, por ejemplo:

```
public enum DefaultCountries {

    COL("COL", "Colombia"), 
    ARG("ARG", "Argentina"),
    PER("PER", "Perú");
    ...
```

Comment: Sí es posible con *Java Reflection* ([por ejemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25444544/870248)), aunque, en mi opinión, un mapa (si quieres, con `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)`) podría ser más conveniente.

Comment: Eso no tendría mucho sentido, si el cargado se hace en runtime, entonces el enum solo estaría accesible en runtime (sus valores no podrían ser utilizados en tiempo de compilación) No imagino para qué podría servirte tal cosa.

Comment: de acuerdo con los dos... se puede hacer, aunque es muy poco práctico. En mi opinion, un `Map` rellenado desde un fichero de properties y apoyado por constantes en una clase java me parece una solución más rápida, práctica y elegante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si esto te sirve:

```
    public enum Constants {
    PROP1,
    PROP2;

    private static final String PATH = "/constantes.properties";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Constants.class);

    private static Properties   properties;

    private String          value;

    private void init() {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(Constants.class.getResourceAsStream(PATH));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("No se pudo cargar el archivo " + PATH + " desde esa ruta.", e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        value = (String) properties.get(this.toString());
    }

    public String getValue() {
        if (value == null) {
            init();
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Necesitas un archivo de propiedades con las propiedades como si las usaras en un enum:

constantes.enum:

```
#Este es el archivo de propiedades...
PROP1=some text
PROP2=some other text
```

Ahora lo importas la clase como estática:

```
import static com.some.package.Constants.*;
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
System.out.println(PROP1);
```

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908973/java-property-file-as-enum) en ingles.